# FancyBox - how to resize when add content inside afterShow ( after youtube iframe )

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I would like to add some additional content ( just a div with small amount of text ) to a fancybox that contains a youtube video and for the window to resize automatically.

My html:

```
<a class="fancyboxVid fancybox.iframe" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Y79hyUt4dn4?enablejsapi=1&wmode=opaque">
        <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Y79hyUt4dn4/sddefault.jpg" />
</a>
```

Javascript :

```
$(".fancyboxVid").fancybox({
                autoSize: true,
                autoResize: true,
                scrolling:'no',
                aspectRation:false,
                afterShow: function () {
                    var iframe = this.content;
                    var subtitlesEl = $("<div>Subtitles : <div id='subtitle' style='display: inline-block;'></div></div>");
                    iframe.after(subtitlesEl);

                    $.fancybox.update()
                }
            });
```

Update is having no effect.

Thanks

Tony

Edit - Adding the title works although I am not sure if that is any different to my approach.  If I resize the iframe and update the fancybox does not change size.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you use the fancybox `title` and the `beforeShow` callback? http://jsfiddle.net/ns1L0Lm9/

Comment: Many thanks JFK that will do nicely